# Trying To Convert a discord rename permission error to a default message when that error comes up, How Do I do That?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@rename.error
async def rename_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, PermissionError):
        await ctx.send("I don't have the permission to do that!¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
    else:
        raise error
```

This is my current code. What I'm trying to do is make my bot come up with a default response instead of telling raising an erro in my console when it doesn't have the permission to rename a certain admin. I'm completely new to this error conversion thing and I actually copy and pasted this but it still doesn't work for me. Can someone help me out?

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

This is the error that I'm trying to convert to a default message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.on_command_error) event, which has two arguments:

- `ctx` → [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.ext.commands.Context) object
- `error` → [`CommandError`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.ext.commands.CommandError) exeception (which inherits from [`DiscordExeption`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.DiscordException))

---

How to use it:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.event #or client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError) and "Missing Permissions" in str(error):
        await ctx.send("I don't have the permission to do that!¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
    else:
        raise error
```

---

You'll find every API errors [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#ext-commands-api-errors).

Comment: Thank you for the fast and informative reply. Unfortunately, I still find myself in a predicament.

Comment: I've edited the code, the error might be a `CommandInvokeError` instance. If it still doesn't work, pls print type(error) just before the if statement (You can also delete your answer since it is not, you can edit your question with your code)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and effort. I really appreciate people like you who teach people like me. :>It's working now! :D